# SQL - Using functions within CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have two fields, `Days_since_last_Open` (Number) and `last_login_dt` (Date). I want to compare them and whichever one is lower place that value in `Days_Since_Last_Activity`. To do this I have this case statement inside my query:

```
Case
  When c.Days_Since_Last_Open < DateDiff(d,a.last_login_dt,GETDATE())
    Then c.Days_Since_Last_Open

  When DateDiff(d,a.last_login_dt,GETDATE()) < c.Days_Since_Last_Open
    Then DateDiff(d,a.last_login_dt,GETDATE()) 
End As Days_Since_Last_Activity
```

However, nothing is populated into Days_Since_Last_Activity. My thought is is has something to do with running a Datediff function inside the CASE statement, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Oh man, I can only guess that it's MS SQL Server, but why do I have to?

Comment: What, exactly, ia the issue/problem that you are facing? It is not apparent in your post.

Comment: The problem is Days_since_Last_activity is not being populated, so something is wrong within the case statement, perhaps due to the datediff function inside? and yes this is MS SQL Server

Comment: your case statement lacks a branch for the condition `DateDiff(d,a.last_login_dt,GETDATE()) = c.Days_Since_Last_Open`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `CASE` should look like this

```
CASE
  WHEN c.Days_Since_Last_Open < DATEDIFF(d, a.last_login_dt, GETDATE())
  THEN c.Days_Since_Last_Open
  ELSE DATEDIFF(d, a.last_login_dt, GETDATE())
END AS Days_Since_Last_Activity
```

Comment: @user1180997 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?